# Normalizing a dataframe having several conditions, R

Tags: r, function, nan, na, normalize

I have a data frame (df), which contains `NA` and numbers. I want to normalize it having the following conditions:

- if a column contains only `NA`, leaves it as it is.
- if a column contains only a number while the rest of values in that column are equal to `NA`, change that value to `1` and `NA`(all `NA` in that column) to `0`.
- if a column contains numbers, normalize it.

I did the following attempt, which doesn't work.

```
normalize<-function(x) {
  x <- as.numeric( as.character( x ))
  if(sum(!is.na(x) == 1)) {
    x[which(!is.na(x))] <- 1
    x[which(is.na(x))] <- 0
    return(x)
  } else if(sum(!is.na(x) == 0)) {
    x <- NA
    return(x)
  } else if(sum(!is.na(x) > 1)) {
    y <- (x-min(x, na.rm=TRUE))/(max(x, na.rm=TRUE)-min(x, na.rm=TRUE))
    return(y)
  } 
}

as.data.frame(lapply(df, normalize))
```

Data sample:

```
df <- data.frame(c(123,534,7567,2345,3456,3476,NA,765), c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA), c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,354,NA,NA))
```

Comment: Check your brackets on the if. The first criteria will return true on everything other than all na, the second one seems to work by chance. Currently y will be 1, NA, or a vector of values `(x_i  - min(x)) / (range(x)` I dont imagine this is the intention

Comment: Please clarify your conditions. In your question, I see: (a) if the column is all NA, leave it. (text and code); (b) If it has a single non-NA value, change that value to 1 and all NA to 0 (text, buggy in code); (c) If a column "contains numbers", normalize it (if by "contains numbers" you mean "all other cases", text and code), but buggy because if your column has multiple copies of a single value you will divide by 0.

Answer (score 2):

Your conditions did not work properly: `sum(!is.na(x)==1)` for example is not what you want, because you want the `sum` over `!is.na(x)` and not the sum of `!is.na(x) == 1`.

The following does the job:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(123,534,7567,2345,3456,3476,NA,765), b = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA), c = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,354,NA,NA))

normalize<-function(x){
  if(sum(!is.na(x))==1){
    x[which(!is.na(x))] <- 1
    x[which(is.na(x))] <- 0
    return(x)
  }else if(sum(!is.na(x))==0){
    x <- NA
    return(x)
  }else if(sum(!is.na(x)>1)){
    y <- (x-min(x, na.rm=TRUE))/(max(x, na.rm=TRUE)-min(x, na.rm=TRUE)) 
    return(y)
  } 
}

as.data.frame(lapply(df, normalize))
              a  b c
[1,] 0.00000000 NA 0
[2,] 0.05519956 NA 0
[3,] 1.00000000 NA 0
[4,] 0.29848601 NA 0
[5,] 0.44773573 NA 0
[6,] 0.45042249 NA 1
[7,]         NA NA 0
[8,] 0.08623168 NA 0
```

Comment: If I compare the result that I get from the standard form of normalization, which is
normalize<-function(x){
  x <- as.numeric( as.character( x ))
  y <- (x-min(x, na.rm=TRUE))/(max(x, na.rm=TRUE)-min(x, na.rm=TRUE))
  return(y)
}
with yours (the first column), I see some difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
normalize<-function(x) {
    sapply(x, function(y) {if(all(is.na(y))) {y}
           else if(sum(!is.na(y))!=1) {helper<- (y-min(y, na.rm=TRUE))/(max(y, na.rm=TRUE)-min(y, na.rm=TRUE)) 
                                      helper}
           else if(sum(!is.na(y))==1) {helper<-ifelse(is.na(y),0,1)
                 helper}
    })
}
```

Result:

```
normalize(df)

              a  b c
[1,] 0.00000000 NA 0
[2,] 0.05519956 NA 0
[3,] 1.00000000 NA 0
[4,] 0.29848601 NA 0
[5,] 0.44773573 NA 0
[6,] 0.45042249 NA 1
[7,]         NA NA 0
[8,] 0.08623168 NA 0
```

Comment: Thanks but your code generates 1 for the first column of the data frame, which is not correct

Comment: Right you are - silly mistake of mine. Fixed the code above.

Comment: the normalization means scaling our data in a range of 0 to 1. After looking at your result, I see negative values and also a value which is more than 1.

Comment: That's not what I understand for normalization to mean. What's wrong with the other solution given above, then?

Comment: Dear @iod, I guess you forgot to test your script.

Comment: How so? Works fine on my end. It's just that my code includes the sapply internally, so you can give the `df` itself as the argument.